# Can we add or delete data directly into database through Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa

Can we add or delete data directly into database from programming in Sitecore SXA?

Can we add .edmx in Sitecore and perform create/update/delete operation through it ?

Comment: Hi Ajay, 

Can you clarify please, what exact data you want to add or remove from the database?

Comment: Try to add new table in the database and perform CRUD operation.

Comment: Why would you want to add new tables? The Sitecore DB is Sitecore's. Leave it alone and use the API as Dawid said. If you want to store external data, use a different database.

Comment: Yes, we are using external database for performing CRUD operation. With external database can we perform CRUD operation directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not do such things! All database operations should be done through the Sitecore APIs. SXA is also using Sitecore APIs and it is never accessing the database directly.
Sitecore is doing a lot of processing around basic database operations (e.g.: while saving an item) so you can break the database easily when you will start to manually manipulate it.

Only through Sitecore APIs!